# SIGSEGV MAPERR in Racket when calling Raylib via FFI

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, ffi

I'm trying to use Raylib (https://www.raylib.com/, https://github.com/raysan5/raylib) from Racket code via FFI. Here is the most simple example:

```
#lang racket
(require ffi/unsafe
         ffi/unsafe/define)

; raylib shared object must be available for Racket
; for example, in Linux it must be in
; ~/.racket/<racket-version>/lib> or /usr/lib/racket
(define-ffi-definer define-raylib (ffi-lib "libraylib" #:global? #t))

(define-raylib BeginDrawing (_fun  -> _void))
(define-raylib CloseWindow (_fun -> _void))
(define-raylib EndDrawing (_fun -> _void))
(define-raylib InitWindow (_fun _int _int _string -> _void))
(define-raylib SetTargetFPS (_fun _int -> _void))
(define-raylib WindowShouldClose (_fun -> _int))

(void InitWindow 640 480 "Test window")
(void SetTargetFPS 60)

(define (main-loop)
        (BeginDrawing)
        (EndDrawing)
        (if (= (WindowShouldClose) 0)
            (main-loop)
            (CloseWindow)))

(main-loop)
```

But even this very simple example crashes with the message:

```
SIGSEGV MAPERR si_code 1 fault on addr (nil)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Looks like it crashes when calling `BeginDrawing()` function. The code of this function is also very simple:

```c
// Setup canvas (framebuffer) to start drawing
void BeginDrawing(void)
{
    currentTime = GetTime();            // Number of elapsed seconds since InitTimer()
    updateTime = currentTime - previousTime;
    previousTime = currentTime;

    rlLoadIdentity();                   // Reset current matrix (MODELVIEW)
    rlMultMatrixf(MatrixToFloat(downscaleView));       // If downscale required, apply it here
}
```

Functions with `rl` prefix are OpenGL wrappers. May it be an OpenGL context issue?

I tried to call the same functions in Guile Scheme and in Guile all works great.

Comment: It looks like you're not actually calling either `InitWindow` or `SetFPS`? Instead of `(void InitWindow 640 480 "Test window")` don't you want `(InitWindow 640 480 "Test window")`?

Comment: Yes, now it works, thank you! What a stupid error.

Please repeat you suggestion as an answer so i'll can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually calling either `InitWindow` or `SetFPS`.

Instead of `(void InitWindow 640 480 "Test window")`, try `(InitWindow 640 480 "Test window")`.